# How to upload large files to azure container using .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, file-upload, azure-blob-storage

I was trying to upload large files to an azure container using a windows form application.

Since the file size was large, I couldn't upload it as a single block.

A method to upload large files as set of blocks were figured out. 
I am posting the code here hoping to help someone having similar requirement.

Answer (score 3):

We can upload large files to azure container by using `Block blobs`.

`Block blobs` are comprised of blocks, each of which is identified by a block ID.

When we upload a block to a blob, it is associated with the specified block blob, but it does not become part of the blob until you commit a list of blocks that includes the new block's ID.

Block IDs are strings of equal length within a blob.

Block client code usually uses base-64 encoding to normalize strings into equal lengths. 
When using base-64 encoding, the pre-encoded string must be 64 bytes or less.

For more info read the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/understanding-block-blobs--append-blobs--and-page-blobs#about-block-blobs).

The following code, splits the source file into multiple byte arrays of size 10MB each. 
Each byte array is uploaded as blocks using **[Put Block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-block)** operation. 
These blocks will be associated with the specified `Block blob`.

Later the blockIDs are commited using **[Put Block List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-block-list)** operation, which will create the blob from the uploaded blocks using the blockIDs.

```
public string UploadFile(string sourceFilePath)
{
    try
    {
        string storageAccountConnectionString = "AZURE_CONNECTION_STRING";
        CloudStorageAccount StorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageAccountConnectionString);
        CloudBlobClient BlobClient = StorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer Container = BlobClient.GetContainerReference("container-name");
        Container.CreateIfNotExists();
        CloudBlockBlob blob = Container.GetBlockBlobReference( Path.GetFileName(sourceFilePath) );
        HashSet<string> blocklist = new HashSet<string>();

        byte[] fileContent = File.ReadAllBytes(sourceFilePath);
        const int pageSizeInBytes = 10485760;
        long prevLastByte = 0;
        long bytesRemain = fileContent.Length;

        do
        {
            long bytesToCopy = Math.Min(bytesRemain, pageSizeInBytes);
            byte[] bytesToSend = new byte[bytesToCopy];
            Array.Copy(fileContent, prevLastByte, bytesToSend, 0, bytesToCopy);
            prevLastByte += bytesToCopy;
            bytesRemain -= bytesToCopy;

            //create blockId
            string blockId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            string base64BlockId = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(blockId));

            blob.PutBlock(
                base64BlockId,
                new MemoryStream(bytesToSend, true),
                null
                );

            blocklist.Add(base64BlockId);

        } while (bytesRemain > 0);

        //post blocklist
        blob.PutBlockList(blocklist);

        return "Success";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return ex.Message;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, it helps me a lot.

Comment: @jophab    I want to upload more than 1gb file, by using this code it took more than 50min time to upload, Any faster way to upload a file.